# Инструкция по git

Tags: git

У меня возникли несколько вопросов в ходе работы с git

1. Как всегда иметь последнюю версия git repository
2. Каким правилам надо следовать чтобы не получить конфликти при git push
3. Нужно ли сделать синхронизацию при клоне git repository. (HEAD -> main, origin/main) потому что при клоне так не отображается, надо сделать слияние веток.
4. Как вернутся к определенной версии на удаленном сервере.

На просторах интернета не нашел удовлетворяющего ответа на мой вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `git fetch --all -p`
2. Пушить нужно только прямых потомков того коммита, который запушен перед вами.
   При `git push` обычно вам просто не позволят сделать такой пуш.
3. Если вы ничего сами не делали, то `git pull`
   Если сами что-то добавили локально, то `git checkout main`, `git fetch --all -p`, `git merge origin/main`, `git push`
4. Зачекаутить нужную версию у себя локально, потом `git push -f`, но только любой другой разработчик может после этого все ваши откаты откатить обратно, если у него локально сохранилась старая история коммитов )))